# How do I check if two timestamps are on consecutive days in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

How do I check if two timestamps are on consecutive days in PostgreSQL? I've tried doing it with the age function but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `date_trunc( 'days' , the_timestamp)` for both

Comment: add some code sample what have you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to date (using `::date` cast), subtract, (take abs value if you don't know which is the newest and which is the oldest timestamp), and compare to 1:

```
WITH some_data (t1, t2) AS
(
   VALUES ('2017-01-06 10:30'::timestamp, '2017-01-05 09:40'::timestamp)
)

SELECT
    (abs(t2::date - t1::date) = 1) AS t1_and_t2_in_consecutive_days
FROM
    some_data ;
```